# Regions of $4$-dimensional space

Tags: euclidean-geometry

I am confused with the imagining the regions of $4$-dimensional space. I know that this space defines $2^4=16$ regions. Consider half upper space ($8$ regions). so
$(2,3,4,1)$ belongs to the first region ($R_1$) and  $(-2,3,4,1)\in R_2$. what we can say about other regions? for example $(-2,3,-4,1)\in R_?$ I wonder if anyone can spot a way to explain this for me?

Comment: Any sequence $(s_1,s_2,s_3,s_4)$ of signs $s_i\in\{-,+\}$ describes a region (and there are $2^4$ of them), so $(-2,3,-4,1)$ would belong to region $(-,+,-,+)$...

Comment: If I want to counter it, what is it number?

Comment: Is it a ordered set?

Comment: You can order it in many interesting [ways](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/haron/Papers/Conference/binaryFUN.pdf)!  Lexicographic order would be the first choice, probably...